# Quart Bad Request syntax or unsupported method

Tags: python, quart, asgi

Python 3.7 on windows

When running the [sample from quart](https://github.com/pgjones/quart/blob/master/README.rst)

```
from quart import Quart, websocket

app = Quart(__name__)

@app.route('/')
async def hello():
    return 'hello'

@app.websocket('/ws')
async def ws():
    while True:
        await websocket.send('hello')

app.run()
```

When running http://127.0.0.1:5000/ws, got

> ```
> Bad Request
> Bad request syntax or unsupported method
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a JS client to connect to the WebSocket, not just your browser. Let's call it *test-ws.html* :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <script>
    let socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5000/ws");

    socket.onmessage = function(event) {
        alert(`Data received: ${event.data}`);
        socket.close();
    };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

(use python3 -m http.server and go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/test-ws.html to test it in your browser)

Comment: Great. I was not sure about CORS trouble, it might depend on your browser